# Wordpress Slider Revolution Instagram With Facebook Like/Share Button

Tags: jquery, wordpress, instagram, revolution-slider

I need to create an image slider pulling from Instagram using revolution slider. It's pretty straight forward with the plugin. Here's an example:

http://revolution.themepunch.com/wordpress-instagram-gallery/

The problem is, I need to provide viewers with the option to like or share each photo in the gallery. Is there a way to provide that option on a per-slide basis using revolution slider (or any other slider - WordPress or jQuery (been searching for hours)) while pulling images from Instagram?

I am able to add buttons on the manually created slides but I need to add it to slide items pulled in from Instagram while ensuring that when the like/share button is clicked, it likes/shares the image currently in view.

A link to a plugin or direction on how to do this in revolution slider will greatly help.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you're asking specifically. I would start off with a button under the slider thing and make sure you can select the currently active picture first.

Comment: I have a Revolution Slider gallery like the one in the link above. I need to add a FaceBook like/share button. The problem is the images come in dynamically from Instagram. So, is there a way to add the FaceBook like button to each slide even though the images are coming from Instagram?